# Store an object in session

Tags: java, jsp, session, tomcat, servlets

I write the following code to store an object to the HttpSession:

```
JenaOWLModel jenaOwlModel=MyModelFactory.getJenaModel();
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true); 
session.setAttribute("jenamodel", jenaOwlModel);
```

And get the oject in another servlet through the following code:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
JenaOWLModel model=(JenaOWLModel)session.getAttribute("jenamodel");
```

It works well, but I want to know if the object I get from the session is the same object I put into the session or it's just a copy . If I change the object I got from the session, whether the object in session will also change? If it changes, will it need to synchronized the object in session by myself.Whether the tomcat provide a mechanism to synchronized the object in session automatically?

Comment: Your session is thread unsafe only when multiple requests that share the same session arrive simultaneously. But I don't think you should worry about that and synchronization. Do you know why you are worried about the thread safety?

Comment: In my application, I need to manipulate this 'JeneOWLModel' by many sevlets. There are some 'add' operations to this model,I don't think these operations will come simultaneously,but just in case. @Bhesh Gurung

Comment: @BheshGurung The real situation is a little complicated . I want to create a `JenaOWLModel` for every user, so I create in an Map which map the user's session to the JenaOWLModel. In order to share this Map in all servlets I choose to put the Map into Session.Once an user login, I will put an element to the Map. When the user want to operate the JenaOWLModel, I get it from the Map. In this case, I think I should synchronize the Map and every JenaModel in the Map.Since I'm fresh to web develop, I don't know whether this is a good way.Could you give me some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I change the object I got from the session, whether the object in session will also change?

It's the same object, so of course it will change.

> If it changes, will it need to synchronized the object in session by myself.

Yes.

> Whether the tomcat provide a mechanism to synchronized the object in session automatically?

No.

Comment: Should I just use the following way to synchronized the Object?`HttpSession sess = req.getSession(true);
synchronized (sess) {
  sess.setAttribute("USERID", id);
  sess.setAttribute("USERNAME", username);
  ...
}` if I synchronized like this, what will happened if another Servlet use`HttpSession sess = req.getSession(true);`to get the session?

Comment: I'm not aware that you need to synchronize on the session, but you need to synchronize on the object, if it can be shared across sessions, or if you're anticipating multiple connections to the same session.